# undo in QT using QLabel instead of QGraphicsveiw

Tags: qt, undo, qlabel

I'm new in QT .. I have implemented image processing program and I used QLabel to show the image , I want to implement " undo command " but all ways I found were using QGraphicsveiw ... There is any way to implement with label or i have to rewrite the code using QGraphicsveiw 
thank you

Comment: Undo doesn't depend on how you paint the image, but how you organize the operations on the image. They should be stored as single steps that can be reverted or just reapplied onto the original image.

Comment: Have a look at Qt's undo framework (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qundo.html), depending on what you are trying to achieve this can help you. There is also a little example painting application that makes use of this framework (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html)

Comment: oops, seems that it isn't a Qt example, but this code that I once found on Github: https://github.com/kkonopko/Paint